# Trouble installing a new package using Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, installation, package

I'm trying to install a package 'backtesting' in my Anaconda prompt by typing 'pip install backtesting' but getting EnvironmentError......

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\users\james\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\~il\_imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

How do I 'Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.'? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please try using below:

```
pip install backtesting --user
```

I tried it and successfully installed the package.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is the correct '--user' usage.

I find when I cannot install with conda or pip keywords, I simply add the module to  the environment variables.

You can do this by accessing your search field on your taskbar and type 'Environment variable' (minus the single quotes) which will produce a window allowing you the option to edit environment vars.

Or you can go directly to 'System Properties' and select the 'Advanced' tab. On the bottom right is a button for environment variables. Clicking on environment variables
you are taken to a new window.

Selecting 'New' from the 'System Variables' field, you want to add the full path of your project solution and once saved your program can 'see' the module. The clincher is you must restart your computer after adding the variable, once the computer is back up the edited 'Environment Variable' becomes effective. You will be able to use the import statement like you always do at the start of program without the error.